# how to divide a string without any index in java

Tags: java, string

I have a String like this `"+91 2895675148 / +91 123456789 / +91 987654321"`. I want to split above string into

```
 String str1 = +91 2895675148

 String str2 = +91 1234567

 String str3 = +91 987654321
```

How to make separate the above numbers from string in java without using index as a parameter

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String string = "+91 2895675148 / +91 123456789 / +91 987654321";
String[] sections = string.split(" / ");
String part1 = parts[0]; // +91 2895675148
String part2 = parts[1]; // +91 123456789
String part3 = parts[2]; // +91 987654321
```

Please view for more methods: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java?lq=1)

Comment: I want to replace \n character instead of  '/' this. How to do that . Is I have to follow the same method??

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want to replace / with \n in the String ? In that case use String[] sections = string.split("\\\n\\]"); Since \n is a special newline character you have to escape it.

Comment: how to get each number into separate string? I mean str1 = +91 2895675148, str2 = +91 123456789 etc

Comment: String part1 = parts[0]; // +91 2895675148
String part2 = parts[1]; // +91 123456789
String part3 = parts[2]; // +91 987654321

Answer (score 1):

Your can use [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))("/") which returns array of string.

Eg.

```
String str = "+91 2895675148 / +91 123456789 / +91 987654321";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split("/")));
```

out put :-

```
[+91 2895675148 ,  +91 123456789 ,  +91 987654321]
```

Comment: how to get each number into separate string? I mean str1 = +91 2895675148, str2 = +91 123456789 etc.